# Javascript regular expression for multiple words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that will account for the possible words "-hello,", "hello,", "-money,", "money," and it will replace these words if they exist, my current code is like

`let regex = /(-?hello,-?money)/gi`

but this doesnt work please help me find where this goes wrong, thank you

Comment: Within a group `()`, a comma `,` is interpreted literally. You're likely looking for the `|` token.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `|` (Alternation) instead of the comma.

```
let regex = /(-?hello|-?money)/gi
```

Comment: Nitpick: the `|` token denotates an "alternative" - while it certainly functions like a logical OR, it's not the exact terminology. Still, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use an alternation only for the words and surround it with word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial matches.

```
let regex = /-?\b(?:hello|money)\b/gi
```

- `-?` Match an optional hyphen
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `hello` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `money` Match literally
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBQHP4/1)

```js
let regex = /-?\b(?:hello|money)\b/gi;
[
  "-hello",
  "hello",
  "-money",
  "money",
  "test money nomoney",
  "test -hello hellow"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "[replacement]")));
```